# Angular2 - What is the best practice to notify a directive when a component is updated?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have a tooltip directive thar uses a component as its template. While creating the component dynamicly, the tooltip DOM element is not ready yet with its innerHtml. The component will get its real width for example only after `ngAfterViewInit` event.

But the directive don't know when the component template has completed rendering. Can I watch the private argument of a component (from directive) and know when its being changed/updated?

**tootlipComponentTemplate**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-container',
  template: `<div #tooltipContent  [innerHTML]="htmlStr"></div>`
})
export class TooltipContainer implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('tooltipContent') elementRef: ElementRef;

  width: number;   
  htmlStr: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() { // this is the place when I really getting the tooltip width
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit: " + this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
    this.width = this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
  }

}
```

**tooltipDirective**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myTooltip]'
})
export class myTooltipDirective {

  private tooltip: ComponentRef<TooltipContainer>;
  private innerHtml: string;

  @HostListener("mouseenter", ['$event'])
  show(event:MouseEvent): void {

    // .. creating the tooltip with factory ..

    console.log(this.tooltip.instance.width); // its undefined at this point !!! //

  }


  constructor() {}      

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div [myTooltip]="myTextOrHtml">text with tooltip on mouseOver</div>
```

Comment: show the code how they are used in `html`

Comment: is this code  `<div [myTooltip]="myTextOrHtml">text with tooltip on mouseOver</div>` part of component template?

Comment: no, this is the way I want users to use the tooltip directive

Comment: so how is `TooltipContainer` component relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `@Output()` to your directive to notify the host component

```
export class TooltipContainer implements AfterViewInit {

  @Output()
  domReady:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild('tooltipContent') elementRef: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() { // this is the place when I really getting the tooltip width
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit: " + this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
    this.width = this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.domReady.next(null);
  }
```

```
<div [myTooltip]="myTextOrHtml" (domReady)="notifyParent()">text with tooltip on mouseOver</div>
```

Comment: The problem here is that using tooltip directive, the user will need also to write the domReady event?

Comment: Yes. How else would you define how to make the parent aware of the tooltip to be ready? There might be other ways but for that I would need more information about your requirements. What should happen when the tooltip is ready?

Comment: the directive should be simple to use. I'm looking for a way that the directive will know when the component template is ready, but this is something the user should be taking care off

Comment: the directive don't have any template, so know event function can be used . Maybe there is a way ro fire event from component to directive?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Why would the directive need a template to fire an event? Sure you can fire an event from component to directive, but I don't know how to demonstrate because I don't know about what component you're talking to and how it's related to the directive.

Comment: I think I should have asked simple - How directive and component can communicate? While the component change something, how the directive can know about it

Comment: I think you should show a concrete example with a component and a directive where the code shows how the directive and the component are related and when and how you want to communicate what data from where to where.